# How to add a background image or theme through CSS?

Tags: html, css, user-interface

Am new to html and learning to design an UI. I wanted to add a background image or theme through the below code. But it's displaying only the color ,not the image.Please let me know how can i achieve it.

```html
<!Document html>
<html lang="en">
<base href="https://abcd.com">
<head>
<title>abcd</title>
</head>
<style>
body{
background-image: url("paper.gif");
background-color: #cccccc;
}
</style>

<body>
<h1 align="center" style="color:brown;position:absolute;top: 3%; left: 41%;">abcd</h1>
</div>
<h2 style="color:skyblue; position:absolute;top: 20%; left: 39%;">Login</h2>
<div style="position:absolute;top: 26%; left: 39%; width:300px;height:120px;border:1px solid #000;"></div>
<form name="login" style="font-size:larger;position:absolute;top: 27%; left: 40%;">
            Username : <input type="text" name="userid"/><br></br>
            Password : <input type="password" name="pswrd"/><br></br>
            <input class="btn btn-primary" style="font-size:medium;background-color: #FFF8DC; position:absolute;top: 95%; left: 50%;" type="button" onclick="check(this.form)" value="Login"/>
            <input style="font-size:medium;background-color: #FFF8DC; position:absolute;top: 95%; left: 75%;" type="reset" value="Cancel"/>
        </form>

</body>
</html>
```

I have placed the image in C:\Users\myuser\Pictures\HTML

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have put image path like:  `url("paper.gif")` then put your image in same folder where your html file has.

You have written correct way. Just set proper path.

```
background-image: url("paper.gif");
```

Or you want to set c: drive path the you can.

```
background-image: url("file://C:/Users/myuser/Pictures/HTML/paper.gif");
```

But i will not recommend it.

You can put image in `images` folder and give path like:

```
background-image: url("images/paper.gif");
```

Comment: Just want to know if it supports jpg files? because I have kept the html file and the lpg image in the same folder "HTML" but still it's not working.Please help me..

Comment: @Rahul I think `<base href="http://abcd.com">` will cause you. try remove it and check.

Comment: No Ketan, That is also not helpful. Still the image isnt getting displayed.

Comment: @Rahul then try to clear all the  elements inside body part and remove `<base href="https://abcd.com">
<head>
<title>abcd</title>
</head>` and just give `background-image` and check is it working? I ma facing same issue and now, solved

Comment: Wow.it's working now. But again after adding the elements , it's not working.what could be the reason?

Answer (score 2):

Be sure that the path to the image is correct. Your syntax is right, just make sure of the path.
You can also change background properties to

```
background-position: center;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
```

It will center your background image.